# como crear ventanas dentro de un frame en Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Buen dia, estoy comenzando a programar en Tkinter y requiero crear una aplicacion de escritorio en la cual dentro de un area de trabajo se pueden abrir multiples ventanas pero estas solo se ven desde la misma area de trabajo, como pueden apreciar en la imagen inferior.

[image: Aplicacion de escritorio donde se muestra las ventanas en cascada]

he creado con toplevel pero me crea una ventana hija que no esta amarrada a un frame.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo no requieres generar nuevas ventanas, si no cambiar la vista de la ventana principal. Además no añades un código a la pregunta, es difícil saber que está pasando realmente.

Comment: Por default, tkinter no puede hacer esto. Puedes usar una función como la que indican en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764908/window-inside-window ; sino, para un uso más o menos similar, usaría quizás `ttk.Notebook()`